# MySQL - Problems caused by SQL Security definer or invoker

Tags: mysql, view

I have a view used to be defined as:

```
> **CREATE 
>     ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
>     DEFINER = `user1`@`localhost` 
>     SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `schema1`.`view1` AS
>     select 
>        ...
>     from
>      ...
>     where
>      ...**
```

The user1 has all privileges to the schema1's objects. And if I, as user2,

```
> select * from view1
```

, it works fine. But If I do:

```
   SELECT * FROM schema1.view1 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.txt'  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
```

I got error saying:

> Error Code: 1356. View 'schema1.view1' references invalid table(s) or
>   column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use
>   them   0.000 sec

If I changed the definition of view from **"SQL SECURITY DEFINER" to "SQL SECURITY INVOKER"**, and do the above query again (and I also have full privileges to the objects of the schema1), it works.

Can anybody explain why this happens? Thank a lot.

Comment: Can anyone please take a look? Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you paste the relevant output of SHOW GRANTS FOR user2@.... and user1@... somewhere accessible (e.g. pastebin)?

Comment: QUESTIONS: 1) What version of MySQL are you using ? 2) Have done a recent upgrade of MySQL ? 3) What version of MySQL did you use when you created the view ? 4) What is the output of `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='mysql' andf table_name='user';` ?

Answer (score 0):

i got same issue
on my case, my resolution re-create the view with change this part from

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`sst_user`@`10.148.0.0/255.255.240.0` SQL SECURITY DEFINER
```

to this

```
CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW
```

and test select the view from user.